# Special case where $I\subseteq J$ implies $R/J\subseteq R/I$ seems to hold

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, formal-power-series, quotient-set

Consider a ring $R$ and two ideals $I,J$ such that $I\subseteq J$. There is a natural projection $R/I\to R/J$ by the isomorphism theorem. There is, in general, no homomorphism going the other way around (there *are* functions as axiom of choice gives right inverses for surjective functions; see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341596/quotients-of-subgroups-inclusion-reversing)).

However, in these [lecture notes](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7Ejimlb/iwasawa.pdf) in at least two proofs (p. $45$ bottom, lemma $4.7$; p. $47$ top, lemma $4.10$) the following "fact" seems to be employed:

> Let $R$ be a ring and $I,J$ ideals such that $I\subseteq J$. Then $R/J\subseteq R/I$.

This fact is applied to $R=\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$ the Iwasawa-algebra (it is, in fact, $\mathcal O_K[[T]]$ for the ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ of a number field $K$ but I do not think that matters structurally speaking) with $I$ and $J$ (some specific) finitely generated ideals. As this already fails in $\mathbb Z$ (consider $I=\langle0\rangle$ and $J=\langle2\rangle$) which is a very well-behaved ring I am not sure what happens here.

> Could someone please explaing what the underlying idea here is? Although it would already help to understand the specific incarnations of the "fact".

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:** After some more thinking, two further comments:

- Ignoring the structure there *is* a natural way of constructing an injective set-function $R/I\to R/J$ (as mentioned above and in the linked Math.SE question). This suffices for the usage in the linked lecture notes as there only something about the cardinality is deduced.
- As my example for $R=\mathbb Z$ illustrated it might be crucial to exclude the zero ideal (as for now I do not see any problems with the unit ideal). At first glance this fixes the problem for $R=\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the underlying idea really is that any set-theoretical surjection $A\to B$ induces a set-theoretical injection $B\to A$ which -- in terms of cardinalities -- gives $|B|\le|A|$. This point of view works out just fine for any application within the notes (and as well within the main source "L.C. Washington: Introduction to Cylcotomic Fields").